# graph.instagram.com unable to get followers_count

Tags: php, api, curl, graph, instagram

Switching over to Instagram Basic Display and Instagram Graph API and running into issue. I've set up the app via Facebook Developer, and received my access_token. When I try to access the followers_count field, I get...

```
{"error":{"message":"Tried accessing nonexisting field (followers_count) on node type (User)","type":"IGApiException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AqHi-QNsUvlSuExA6GOp5A9"}}
```

But with some of the items, I get results. I can receive 'id', 'username', 'media_count', 'ig_id'.

I feel like this is permissions, but not sure what to look for?

Does not work:

```
curl -i -X GET 'https://graph.instagram.com/me/?fields=followers_count&access_token=REMOVED'
```

Example of something that works:

```
curl -i -X GET 'https://graph.instagram.com/me/?fields=media_count&access_token=REMOVED'
```

Comment: Could you post the code your are using to access this data?

Comment: Sure.. added to original post.

Comment: Do you have any documentation from Instagram or Facebook that says `followers_count` is a valid field? They might just not have a field for that.

Comment: You need to use the Graph API, not the Basic Display API for that case, as far as i found out... the available fields of the basic api are listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user

Answer (score 0):

The Basic Display API doesn't have the fields in the definition you can refer it here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user#fields

You need to use the **Instagram Graph API**. `followers_count` & `follows_count`are available only in Instagram Graph API.
It is working as expected, please refer the screenshot of postman below:-
[image]